# how to create a css attribute swapper between two elements?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to make two elements exchange their z-index value. Here's what I've got so far:

```
function zSwapper (beneathElement,underneathElement) {
    var beneathElementZ = $(beneathElement).css('z-index');
    var underneathElementZ = $(underneathElement).css('z-index');

    $(beneathElement).css({'z-index': underneathElementZ});
    $(underneathElement).css({'z-index': beneathElementZ});
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work, because once I change the first element z-index, the second takes that value instead of the one it had in the begining. So, both elements end up having the same z-index, instead of exchanging their values. Is there any way this could be acomplished?

**EDIT:** Well, as it was pointed below, it seems this actually works: http://jsfiddle.net/xGPx2/2/, so there is some other problem with my code. I hope at least someone finds this useful.

Comment: Look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xGPx2/2/). It's your code, and it works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should work fine, maybe it's more css related?
I tested your code, see [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xGPx2/2/)

Comment: Wow, thanks. It seems there might be another problem in my code... I'm trying to figure it out right now.

Comment: @CCrawler don't forget the elements should all be positioned: position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed. Otherwise the z-index won't have any effect

Comment: Yeah, all the elements are properly positioned. It's not a visual issue, I'm actually seeing that both elements are getting the same value out of the function.. that's why I thought the problem was there :P

Answer (score 2):

Do not use an object when setting a css attribute, but [two arguments](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css2).

```
function zSwapper (beneathElement,underneathElement) {
    var beneathElementZ = $(beneathElement).css('z-index');
    var underneathElementZ = $(underneathElement).css('z-index');

    $(beneathElement).css('z-index', underneathElementZ);
    $(underneathElement).css('z-index', beneathElementZ);
}
```

[Check this example](http://jsfiddle.net/UJ36e)

Comment: Mhh, that doesn't seem to change anything. They still end up having the same z-index value, instead of exchanging them.

Comment: This should have exactly the same effect as the code in the Question.

Comment: I added an example that is working. (Comment the function call and the two quares are not exanging z-indices.).

So if it still isn't working, it may be an CSS issue. Something with stacking contexts?
http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-stack-z-index/

Comment: Thanks Mikey. No, it doesn't seem to be a css problem, since when I check the site on firebug, I see both elements get the same z-index values (so it's not just a visual thing)... there may be some other problem on my js, I'm still trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

you could have separate classes which could be exchanges between the two elements

Comment: Yeah, but since I have a lot of elements with different z-index values, what I'm after is a portable function I could use with any pair of elements I want and exchange their values, whatever they may be.